Completeness of the dual space with respect to a weaker norm?
This is probably a very simple question, but I cannot seem to come up with an example.   Let $X$ be a separable Banach space, and let $x_1, x_2, \dots$ be a countable dense subset of its unit ball.  Furthermore, let $Y:=X'$ be the dual of $X$.  The weak-star convergence on bounded sets in $Y$ is metrizable with respect to the metric induced by the norm $$\|y\|_1 := \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i} |\langle y, x_i\rangle|,$$ where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the duality pairing between $Y$ and $X$.  My question is, whether $(Y,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is a complete space?  I suspect that generally speaking it is not, but can one point me to a good example?

@RhysSteele It is only the unit ball of $Y$ that is weak$^\ast$ compact, not $Y$ itself. Furthermore, $|\cdot|_1$ only induces the weak$^\ast$ topology on bounded subsets of $Y$, not on the entirety of $Y$.

@davidgao ah whoops, i misread that Y was a bounded subset of the dual (as should be obvious from the comment about it being closed, which is a silly thing to say about the full space).

It never is, unless $Y$ (equivalently $X$) is finite-dimensional. Indeed, assume to the contrary that $Y$ is complete under $\|\cdot\|_1$. We also note that $\|\cdot\|_1 \leq \|\cdot\|$ (the latter norm is the usual operator norm on $Y = X’$). Thus, the formal identity map $(Y, \|\cdot\|) \to (Y, \|\cdot\|_1)$ is a bijective bounded map between two Banach spaces. So by open mapping theorem, it is a homeomorphism. But the closed unit ball of $(Y, \|\cdot\|)$ is weak$^\ast$ compact, whence compact under $\|\cdot\|_1$, so the homeomorphism above implies the closed unit ball of $(Y, \|\cdot\|)$ is also compact under $\|\cdot\|$. No infinite-dimensional Banach space can have a compact closed unit ball under the norm topology, so this is a contradiction.

thanks a lot!  I can only take solace in the fact that indeed, this question was very simple :)

@rafexiap FWIW, I cannot come up with an explicit counterexample either, only this abstract argument. An explicit counterexample seems very hard to conjure and depends very much on what $x_i$ are. I think the basic philosophy here is that given two “natural” norms on a space s.t. one of the norms is complete, either the two norms are equivalent, or the second norm is incomplete.
